# (1) Sum of two factorials in two ways; (2) Value of $a^{2010}+a^{2010}+1$ given $a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1=0$.

Tags: proof-verification, factorial, factoring, prime-factorization

Question $1$:

Does there exist an integer $z$ that can be written in two different ways as $z=x!+y!$,where $x,y\in \mathbb N$ and $x\leq y$?

> Answer: $0!=1!$ so $0!+2!=3=1!+2!$

Question $2$:

If $a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1=0$, find the  value of $a^{2010}+a^{2010}+1$.

> Answer: If $a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1=0$ then $$(a-1)(a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)=0\implies a^5-1=0\implies a=1$$So the value of the required expression is $3$

I think that it is wrong as  at $a=1$,$\frac{a^5-1}{a-1}$ is not defined.

Please give me some hints  to solve thes problems?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time!

Comment: And $a^5=1$ need not imply $a=1$; take $a=e^ {2\pi i/5}\neq 1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:i'll take care of that next time

Comment: About the first question, I am curious to know if it is possible to prove that the solution you have found is the unique solution

Comment: @Raffaele:it is not unique.Infact there are infinite such numbers $0!+n!=n!+1!$,where $n\in \mathbb N$

Comment: @gsamaras: Agreed and fixed! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second solution is not so wrong

$a^5-1=0$ has five solutions, the five complex fifth roots of unity. Namely

$$\left(a_0=1,\;a_1 = -\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}-i \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}},\;a_2 = -\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+i \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}},\\a_3 = -\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}-i \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}},\;a_4 = -\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+i \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}\right)$$

One of them, $a=1$, is not a root of the fourth degree equation 
$$a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1=0$$
but the other four actually are because $$a^5-1=(a-1)(a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)$$

So plugging $a^5=1$ in the $a^{2000}+a^{2010}+1$  is perfectly legal and the actual result is  $3$

Hope this is useful

Comment: :but $a=1$  is  not satisfying $a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1=0$

Comment: That's why you substitute the other roots of $a^5-1=0\;$ ! Look at my edit...

Comment: This is best solution

Answer (score 6):

The first solution is wrong, because $3\neq z!$ for any $z$.

---

The second solution is wrong.

If $a=1$, then $a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1=1+1+1+1+1\neq 0$, so it is obvious you made a serious mistake in your second solution.

In particular, you multiplied the equation by $(a-1)$, which **of course** produced a solution of $a=1$.

Comment: Not sure about the first solution. The problem specifies $z!=x!+y!$, however, in OP's solution $$3=0!+2!=1!+2!$$ $3$ is not equal to $z!$ for any integer $z$.

Comment: @Jazzachi You're right, thanks.

Comment: sorry , it was a typo,it is $z$

Comment: @PKStyles Then your first solution is ok, so long as you consider $0$ to be an element of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @5xum:What if $0$ is not a natural number?

Comment: @PKStyles Then obviously, your solution is no longer valid

Comment: @5xum:I did'nt mean that, i wanted to know what will be the solution then?I tried  evaluating by taking two at a time, $x!+y!$,where $x,y \in ${$1,2,3,4,5,,6,7,8,9,10$},but no value is same

Comment: @PKStyles There is no solution if you do not allow $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67164/discussion-between-pk-styles-and-5xum).

Comment: @PKStyles If you do not allow $0!$, then there is no solution, because any factorial past the first two completely dwarfs any that come before it.

Comment: What if a is complex